# MySQL date conversion

Tags: php, mysql, date-format

I have inherited a MySQL database which (for historical reasons) contains a field which stores a date as number of days since **1900-01-01**. I want to be able to select a date_format() version of this date but can't figure a way of doing so.
Is there a way of manipulating the contents of the column such that I can pass the manipulated value to date_format() so it is recognised as a valid date?
I realise there is a solution to this which involves doing one query, then manipulating the field (in PHP) then passing back in as a secondary query - but I need this to be a single query solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the MySql FROM_DAYS() function what you're looking for - see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-days) for docs?

However, depending on your database design and use case, you might consider adding a column with the date (result of FROM_DAYS()), so that you can do queries against that column. When you have to apply a function to a column before being able to use this in a query, it should ring warning bells that these queries could be quite inefficient to run.

Comment: Thanks - just what I needed. The efficiency is not too important in this case as long as it can be done in one query.

Answer (score 1):

Can you create views and functions on the database? If so I would create a function with the query you are currently using to convert the time and then create a view using that function to display the time as a timestamp. This will improve your efficiency and make your php code cleaner :)

Comment: Can't create views or functions unfortunately